# Reference not set error at empty line

Tags: c#, arrays, split, streamreader

I get this error when I read from a file and the file has an empty line, I want the loop to stop at the empty line but I get this error, how should I do this?

```
string[] delim = new string[] { "," };
bool eof=false;
int k=0;
do
{
   string[] linie =  sr.ReadLine().Split(delim, StringSplitOptions.None);

   if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(linie[0]))
      eof = true;
   else
   {
      A[k] = double.Parse(linie[0]);
      l[k] = Convert.ToInt32(linie[1]);
      c[k] = Convert.ToInt32(linie[2]);
   }
   k++;
 }
 while (!eof);
```

The error is here: `string[] linie =  sr.ReadLine().Split(delim, StringSplitOptions.None);`.

Comment: Try `File.ReadLines`. You will find it easier to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break your statement into multiple lines:

```
String line = sr.ReadLine();
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
{
    string[] linie = line.Split(delim, StringSplitOptions.None);
    //The rest of your code
}
```

As Jeff has pointed out, if you have > .Net4 then you can use `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`

Comment: Best to still use IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line), though.  No reason to switch to NullOrEmpty.

Comment: @Jeff, I was using .Net3.5

Comment: @guNNer2bad. Please accept this answer as the solution if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

When you reach the end of the file, `sr.ReadLine()` returns `null`. So when you attempt to split `null`, you'll get a `NullReferenceException`.

You should check for null before doing your split.

An alternate way of organizing your could could be:

```
string line;
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
}
```